# JIRA jql to get all users who have touched a ticket

Tags: jira, jql, jira-agile

I had been trying to get the list of all issues who had been assigned to some one else at some time and changed at present

I had tried this piece of code

```
assignee was "UserA" and assignee != "UserA"
```

It would return all issues that this user had previously been assigned.But how can i get all issues from all users.Something similar to this

```
assignee was "AllUsers" and assignee != "AllUsers"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get all the issues where the assignee has changed then you could do:

```
assignee changed
```

However I don't believe there is a way that you can do a JQL to search for all issues where a user was assigned to it but no longer is short of [creating your on JIRA plugin that adds a JQL function](https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/jira-platform/search/tutorial-adding-a-jql-function-to-jira).

Comment: It Actually helped i've written aquery like this: assignee changed and assingee in membersOf("ProjectName").